# In golang my go routines are using all cores, but only between 50 and 75% of each core

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

I am using version go1.5.3 linux/amd64 of the go language.  I have a go routine that performs a mathematical operation that takes some time.  Each go routine acts independently and does not have to block.

My systems has 12 cores.  If I spawn 12 go routines, it only takes the average use of all cores up to 31%.  If I use 24 go routines, it brings the average use of all cores up to 49%.  If I use 240, i get 77%.  2400 gives me 76%.

Apparently, the rand.Intn(j) operation is what is slowing it down.  Without it, the cores will run at 100%.

```
func DoSomeMath() int {
    k := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        j := i*i + 2
        k += i * rand.Intn(j)
    }
    return k
}
```

How can I get the program to use all the cores at 100% while using an RNG?

Comment: Is it possible that the goroutines have to wait for some io? E.g reading data from the disk / db?

Comment: At least give us some code that behaves that way. Mathematical operation, long time, does not block - it doesn't mean anything in terms of CPU utilisation. There can be a million reasons why it doesn't perform like you want it to.

Comment: There's no point in guessing. Show us some code: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use a separate rng for each goroutine, so that they're not all waiting for the same lock.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is, the global `rand.*` uses a mutex, so at any given point, you can only generate one random number at a time.

The reason @peterSO's answer works is because there's no mutex now and it's 1 generator per routine, however you can end up with duplicate state if 2 or more goroutines start at the exact nano second, although unlikely.

Look [here](https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go#L233) to see how the global rand works under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase, there are lies, damn lies, and benchmarks.

Despite being asked, you still haven't posted the code necessary to reproduce your issue: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Here's a reproducible benchmark, which uses a PRNG, that should drive your CPUs to close to 100%:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func DoSomeCPU(done <-chan bool) {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    k := 0
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        j := i*i + 2
        k += i * r.Intn(j)
    }
    _ = k
    <-done
}

func main() {
    numCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numCPU)
    done := make(chan bool, 2*numCPU)
    for {
        done <- true
        go DoSomeCPU(done)
    }
}
```

What results do you get when you run this code?

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick.  Making a separate random number generator stopped each go routine from blocking on the global one.  Thank you very much.

Comment: "there are lies, damn lies, and benchmarks". Let us not forget answers to support tickets, which depending on the situation are either worse or (slightly) better than benchmarks.